# How to match pairs of values and then subtract value of a column?

Tags: dplyr, match

I am currently working with a dataset containing all grand slam tennis matches between 2010 and 2019. The data frame contains two rows per match, one row with containing info about one player (the winner) and another containing info about the other player (the loser). The commonality between each of these pairs is the `match_ID` variable.

I would like to create a new variable called rank difference. The idea would be to have for each row the difference in ATP rank between the winner and the loser.

Here is what a subset of the data frame I am working with looks like:

```
# A tibble: 9,290 x 5
# Groups:   player_id [444]
   match_id    player_id   rank winner full_name           
   <chr>       <chr>      <dbl> <fct>  <chr>               
 1 m_2019_A_0  atp_104731     6 True   Kevin Anderson      
 2 m_2019_A_1  atp_105932    20 True   Nikoloz Basilashvili
 3 m_2019_A_2  atp_105430    98 True   Radu Albot          
 4 m_2019_A_3  atp_105882   137 True   Stefano Travaglia   
 5 m_2019_A_4  atp_104269    28 True   Fernando Verdasco   
 6 m_2019_A_5  atp_104655    94 True   Pablo Cuevas        
 7 m_2019_A_7  atp_126774    15 True   Stefanos Tsitsipas  
 8 m_2019_A_8  atp_105777    21 True   Grigor Dimitrov     
 9 m_2019_A_9  atp_126207    39 True   Frances Tiafoe      
10 m_2019_A_10 atp_104745     2 True   Rafael Nadal        
# ... with 9,280 more rows
```

Here is what I tried but did not work:

```
final_match_with_player %>%
group_by(match_id) %>%
mutate(diff_rank = rank[winner == 'True'] - rank[winner == 'False'])
```

Do you have any idea of how I could do that ?

Thank you very much in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this get what you want?

```
# example data
final_match_with_player <- tibble::tribble(
                                ~match_id,   ~player_id, ~rank, ~winner,             ~full_name,
                             "m_2019_A_0", "atp_104731",    6L,    TRUE,       "Kevin Anderson",
                             "m_2019_A_1", "atp_105932",   20L,    TRUE, "Nikoloz Basilashvili",
                             "m_2019_A_2", "atp_105430",   98L,    TRUE,           "Radu Albot",
                             "m_2019_A_3", "atp_105882",  137L,    TRUE,    "Stefano Travaglia",
                             "m_2019_A_0", "atp_106666",   30L,   FALSE,           "Joe Bloggs",
                             "m_2019_A_1", "atp_106667",   40L,   FALSE,             "John Doe",
                             "m_2019_A_2", "atp_106668",   50L,   FALSE,            "Some Body",
                             "m_2019_A_3", "atp_106669",   60L,   FALSE,           "Tennis Pro"
                             )


# create rank_diff
final_match_with_player %>% 
  group_by(match_id) %>% 
  mutate(rank_diff = ifelse(winner, -rank, rank), 
        rank_diff = sum(rank_diff)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Resulting in:

```
A tibble: 8 × 6

  match_id   player_id   rank winner full_name            rank_diff
  <chr>      <chr>      <int> <lgl>  <chr>                    <int>
1 m_2019_A_0 atp_104731     6 TRUE   Kevin Anderson              24
2 m_2019_A_1 atp_105932    20 TRUE   Nikoloz Basilashvili        20
3 m_2019_A_2 atp_105430    98 TRUE   Radu Albot                 -48
4 m_2019_A_3 atp_105882   137 TRUE   Stefano Travaglia          -77
5 m_2019_A_0 atp_106666    30 FALSE  Joe Bloggs                  24
6 m_2019_A_1 atp_106667    40 FALSE  John Doe                    20
7 m_2019_A_2 atp_106668    50 FALSE  Some Body                  -48
8 m_2019_A_3 atp_106669    60 FALSE  Tennis Pro                 -77
```

**Edit upon further information**

It might be easier just to arrange by match_id and rank, then mutate using the lead and lag functions in a case_when conditional:

```
# create rank_diff
final_match_with_player %>% 
arrange(match_id,rank) %>% 
  mutate(rank_diff = case_when(lead(match_id) == match_id ~ lead(rank) - rank, 
                            TRUE ~ lag(rank) - (rank)))
```

Giving:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 6
  match_id   player_id   rank winner full_name            rank_diff
  <chr>      <chr>      <int> <lgl>  <chr>                    <int>
1 m_2019_A_0 atp_104731     6 TRUE   Kevin Anderson              24
2 m_2019_A_0 atp_106666    30 FALSE  Joe Bloggs                 -24
3 m_2019_A_1 atp_105932    20 TRUE   Nikoloz Basilashvili        20
4 m_2019_A_1 atp_106667    40 FALSE  John Doe                   -20
5 m_2019_A_2 atp_106668    50 FALSE  Some Body                   48
6 m_2019_A_2 atp_105430    98 TRUE   Radu Albot                 -48
7 m_2019_A_3 atp_106669    60 FALSE  Tennis Pro                  77
8 m_2019_A_3 atp_105882   137 TRUE   Stefano Travaglia          -77
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It's almost what I would like. However, there is one thing I still can't do. If we take the example of the data you provided, I would like the rank_diff of Kevin Anderson (the player with the highest rank) to be 24 and that of his opponent Joe Bloggs (the player with the lowest rank) to be -24. Same thing with "Nikoloz Basilashvili where I would like to have a rank_diff of 20 while I would like to have a rank_diff of -20 for his opponent, John Doe.

Do you have any idea how I could do that?

Comment: Do you want the rank_diff to depend on who is the winner or just who has the higher rank?

Comment: So in this example, Radu Albot should be -48, and Some Body 48?

Comment: I'd like rank_diff to depend on who has the higher rank.

Comment: Exactly,  Radu Albot should be -48, and Some Body 48. Thanks again for helping me

Comment: How about the new version? Slightly different approach as the rank diff does not seem conditional on the winner value.

Comment: The output on the data example is exactly what I want. Yet, when applying it to my extended data frame, it does not work. I suspect this comes from that fact that rank evolves over time and that a single rank appears several times in the data frame. Can you think of any other explanation for why it might not work ?

Comment: It looks like you have grouped your dataframe by player_id. Try ungroup() first, then run it again - that might help.